# NDSolve does not give me the expected solution

Tags: numerical-integration, differential-equations

I have an assignment where I need to compute chemical reactions by solving ODEs. I use `NDSolve` to do this. However, for one problem it does not give me the predicted answer. My friend uses MATLAB's `ode15s` function to solve it and he gets the correct solution.

Is there any option in `NDSolve` that I should play with to match the correct solution?

Sorry if I don't give much information on the nature of the problem since that would be tedious. However, here is the code I am using:

```
sol[To_?NumericQ] := NDSolve[{
   T'[t] == (-q[t]/V - (uCO[T[t]] nCO'[t] + uO[T[t]] nO'[t] + uO2[T[t]] nO2'[t] + uCO2[T[t]] nCO2'[t]) / ((CvCO[T[t]] nCO[t] + CvO[T[t]] nO[t] + CvO2[T[t]] nO2[t] + CvCO2[T[t]] nCO2[t]))),
   q[t] == 4 Pi r Koil (T[t] - Tenv[t]),
   Tenv[t] == To,
   nCO'[t] == -nCO[t] nO[t] m[t] r1[T[t]] - nCO[t] nO2[t] r2[T[t]] + nCO2[t] m[t] r1b[T[t]] + nCO2[t] nO[t] r2b[T[t]],
   nO'[t] == -nCO[t] nO[t] m[t] r1[T[t]] + nCO[t] nO2[t] r2[T[t]] - 2 nO[t] nO[t] m[t] r3[T[t]] + nCO2[t] m[t] r1b[T[t]] - nCO2[t] nO[t] r2b[T[t]] + 2 nO2[t] m[t] r3b[T[t]],
   nO2'[t] == -nCO[t] nO2[t] r2[T[t]] + nO[t] nO[t] m[t] r3[T[t]] + nCO2[t] nO[t] r2b[T[t]] - nO2[t] m[t] r3b[T[t]],
   nCO2'[t] == nCO[t] nO[t] m[t] r1[T[t]] + nCO[t] nO2[t] r2[T[t]] - nCO2[t] m[t] r1b[T[t]] - nCO2[t] nO[t] r2b[T[t]],
   m'[t] == nCO'[t] + nO'[t] + nO2'[t] + nCO2'[t],
   T[0] == To,
   q[0] == 0.,
   nCO[0] == nCOinit,
   nO[0] == 0.,
   nO2[0] == nO2init,
   nCO2[0] == 0.,
   m[0] == nCOinit + nO2init
   },
  {T, q, Tenv, nCO, nO, nO2, nCO2, m},
  {t, 0.00, tfinal},
  MaxStepSize -> 0.001,
  MaxSteps -> Infinity
  ]
```

Comment: If it isn't giving you what you expect, then what is it giving you? In other words, can you post a plot of the correct solution and the incorrect one?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example; if that's not possible (it usually *is*), at least make the long code you post executable on its own.

Answer (score 11):

If your friend used MATLAB's `ode15s` solver, then your equations are most likely [stiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation), and the default `NDSolve` options are unlikely to give you a numerically stable result unless your step sizes are insanely small. You'll need a stiff solver instead.

For examples on how to proceed in Mathematica, look at [`tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest.html). Specifically, explore the methods `"StiffnessSwitching"`, `"StiffnessTest"` and `"NonStiffTest"`. Since you haven't described your system, there is nothing more I can say at this point, but these hints should give provide a good starting point for you.